# Typeorm Atlas Mongodb serverless instance connection error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typeorm

I'm used to connect typeorm to atlas mongodb free instances and everything works good. Now I'm trying to connect the same way to a new serverless cluster using this configurations:

```
{
    name: `default`,
    type: `mongodb`,
    url: 'mongodb+srv://user:password@production.smi5w.mongodb.net/databaseName',
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    entities: [my entities]
}
```

I'm getting this error: MongoParseError: Text record must only set `authSource` or `replicaSet`

If I just change the url to a free cluster url everything works.
If I try to connect using the params link username, password, host etc... I'm getting a time out.

Can anyone help with this, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: I guess you're using load balancing mode, so you should take the latest node driver that can work with this mode and which allow loadbalanced txt record

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. Probably I'm using the load balancing mode because it is a serverless cluster instance. The thing is that I've followed the atlas guide to connect, using this url. If I try to connect using mongodb driver instead of typeorm everything works good and I'm getting this error just with typeorm. Do you know how can I get this latest node driver you are talking about? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a node developer, but it should be any regular way to get required library(nuget?) version and it should be version 4.1 based on https://docs.mongodb.com/driversnode/current/whats-new/#std-label-version-4

Comment: `I'm getting this error just with typeorm` -
then the typeorm that you use doesn't reference the latest driver (4.1), check the latest typeorm version, the node 4.1 was released recently, so maybe the libraries that use it were not released soon enough, idk

Comment: I don't know how can I thank you sir. For some reason typeorm uses the version 3 of mongodb by default. I just had to install the version 4 manually and everything is running good now. Thank you so much!